# Beautiful Soup extraction of content based on types

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I want to extract the question (type='q') and answer (type='a') pairs as a single data point from the following xml format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<transcript id="001" >
<body>
<section name="Q&amp;A">
      <speaker id="0">
        <plist>
          <p>Thank you. We'll now be conducting the question-and-answer session. <mark type="Operator Instructions" /> Thank you. Please go ahead with your question.</p>
        </plist>
      </speaker>
      <speaker id="3" type="q">
        <plist>
          <p>Good morning. First of all, Happy New Year.</p>
        </plist>
      </speaker>
      <speaker id="2" type="a">
        <plist>
          <p>Happy New Year, sir.</p>
        </plist>
      </speaker>
      <speaker id="3" type="q">
        <plist>
          <p>Thank you. How is your pain now?.</p>
        </plist>
      </speaker>
       <speaker id="2" type="a">
            <plist>
              <p>Oh, it's better now. I think i am healing.</p>
            </plist>
          </speaker>
</section>
</body>
</transcript>
```

i.e. the outputs should be like: ['Good morning. First of all, Happy New Year. Happy New Year, sir.', 'Thank you. How is your pain now?. Oh, it's better now. I think i am healing.']

Can anyone please help me doing this using Beautiful soup? My current code  extracts all the `<p>` tags in the document but the problem with this is that there are other sections (except "Q&A") as well whose `<p>` tags get extracted.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(handler, "html.parser")
texts = []
for node in soup.findAll('p'):
    text = " ".join(node.findAll(text=True))
    #text = clean_text(text)
    texts.append(text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the questions and all the answers using `find_all('speaker', type='q')` and `find_all('speaker', type='a')` respectively. Then use `zip` to join the corresponding question and its answer.

**Code:**

```
questions = soup.find_all('speaker', type='q')
answers = soup.find_all('speaker', type='a')

for q, a in zip(questions, answers):
    print(' '.join((q.p.text, a.p.text)))
```

**Output:**

```
Good morning. First of all, Happy New Year. Happy New Year, sir.
Thank you. How is your pain now?. Oh, it's better now. I think i am healing.
```

If you want it in a list, you can use *list comprehension*:

```
q_and_a = [' '.join((q.p.text, a.p.text)) for q, a in zip(questions, answers)]
print(q_and_a)
# ['Good morning. First of all, Happy New Year. Happy New Year, sir.',
#  "Thank you. How is your pain now?. Oh, it's better now. I think i am healing."]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findAll('speaker', {"type": "q"})` to find the questions and the use `findNext("speaker")` to find the corresponding answer.

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(handler, "html.parser")
for node in soup.findAll('speaker', {"type": "q"}):
    print( node.find("p").text )
    print( node.findNext("speaker").find("p").text)
    print( "--" )
```

**Output:**

```
Good morning. First of all, Happy New Year.
Happy New Year, sir.
--
Thank you. How is your pain now?.
Oh, it's better now. I think i am healing.
--
```